# How to read a zip entry into a postgres table using the JDBC copymanager

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, jdbc, zipinputstream

I am using the JDBC CopyManager library's `copyout` method to backup a postgres table to an AWS S3 bucket as a csv file. This works. I am saving this backup as a zip containing the file in order to save space in the AWS bucket.

I am now working on using the CopyManager library's `copyin` method to restore the backup file to my postgres table and am running into a small issue regarding reading the zipped input stream.

How can I access the zip entry and pass it into the copy manager's `copyin` method? Ideally, I'd like to not need to save any data to disk as an intermediate step between S3 and postgres.

I think this is a good start, but you ZipEntry is not an input stream, so there must be another line or two of code necessary to pass the  zip entry in as an input stream. I am not very experienced working with inputstreams, so I imagine the answer is fairly simple.

```
public void restoreWithCopyManager( int list_id, String backupFileName) throws IOException, SQLException {
    Connection connection = db.getConnection();
    CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager(connection.unwrap(BaseConnection.class));
    ImportBucketConfig bucketConf = Config.get().s3ImportBucket;
    String fileFullPath = backupFileName;

    S3InputStream in = new S3InputStream(bucket, fileFullPath, bucketConf.accessKeyId,
            bucketConf.secretAccessKey, S3Util.findRegion(bucketConf.region));

    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(in);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
    
    long res = copyManager.copyIn("COPY test_copy_table FROM STDIN WITH CSV", zipEntry);
    zis.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my [Copying Entries from ZipInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285325/copying-entries-from-zipinputstream)

You pass the ZipInputStream into the copy function, but must first execute getNextEntry() on the zip input stream in order to set the pointer to the zipped entry.

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(in);
zis.getNextEntry();
long res = copyManager.copyIn("COPY test_copy_table FROM STDIN WITH CSV", zis);
```